# Neo saves Trinity by flying instead of teleporting to her

Tags: plot-explanation, the-matrix-reloaded

In the scene from *The Matrix Reloaded* when Neo is with the Architect and finds out that Trinity is going to get killed instead of flying at super sonic speed why didn't he just teleport and arrive on time to save Trinity from getting shot?

Instead of doing that we all know he flew really fast got to her late but catches her and phases his hand into her body to take the bullet out and fix her injury all within a few mins!

Also previously when the Merovingian traps him and his team is in trouble he  flies off to save them and barely makes it.

Comment: Please try to avoid putting the film's title into the question title in a way that hurts reading flow. It's really not necessary and decreases readability. Mentioning it in the question body is more important.

Comment: What makes you think he can teleport?

Comment: @mattiav27 i am not saying that he can my question is that since he is anomaly within the system can't he just teleport from one point to the next? Perhaps at the time of his greatest need he could have realized that not being able to do so is just another bound he needs to break?

Answer (score 6):

Neo in *The Matrix* movies is an anomaly, which allows him to bend the physics rules of that universe.  We see he can move faster than anyone else, he can propel himself through the air, he can steal the motion from bullets etc.

He shows no ability to teleport, and it doesn't appear to be an ability he has - if he could have gotten to Trinity faster through some other ability, he would have done so.

It's not stated but quite likely that "bending" the rules is the limit of what he can do while in the Matrix.

Comment: he phases his hand inside trinity takes out a bullet and heals her. That is not really bending the laws is it? Also my point is since he is an anomaly in the matrix then materializing from point to another desirable point should be his next logical move.

Comment: There's no evidence it's possible at all - even the programs in the Matrix can't teleport (the agents take over bodies of local matrix residents for example).  The closest you get to teleportation is the doors to different places.  Also bear in mind that the Architect says that Neo can't save her, and never has in all the previous iterations of the Matrix.  So Neo saving Trinity is new, and that means what he does to save her is also new.  Perhaps he is developing new abilities and if the movie didn't end as it did, he would have been able to teleport eventually.  But that's all speculation...

Comment: exactly! Neo saving Trinity was new and hence an introduction of a new ability, in the case of the movie phasing his hand through trinity taking the bullet and healing the wound. But you are right perhaps had the movie been longer or even a different direction was taken then teleportation could have been introduced perhaps with a certain limitation.

Answer (score 2):

Movies establish a set of "rules". For example, space aliens may have ray guns and spaceships, but they may not have mind control.

In *The Maxtrix* trilogy, the filmmakers established the "rules" so that Neo can fly and stop bullets in mid-air, but he can't teleport. They're just the arbitrary rules within that movie's universe.

Comment: Might be worth explaining how these world rules are usually fully signalled or foreshadowed, if not outright demonstrated (with earlier examples) before the climax of a movie, in order to avoid a Deus ex Machina ending (which is often considered something of a let-down by fans in sci fi/fantasy/superhero genres). A hero that gains an *unexplained* ability that conveniently solves a final confrontation would be considered a weak plot point in most narratives - even though it is a very common trope that the hero finds renewed willpower,finally overcomes their own flaws etc, at the last moment.

Comment: @NeilSlater in this case he realised that phasing his hand through Trinity is possible and hence he was not only able to take the bullet out but heal her as well.